# swap the ID of 2 list items using sortable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using a sortable list item and I want when moving an item from position a to position b for the item to have the new position.
for example
*Firsth:1
*second:2
*third:3
 when swaping third into first i shal obtain:
*first:3
*second:2
*third:1

this is what i have tried so far

```
$(function () {
$('#sortable').sortable({
//to prevent items from moving around when draging
containment: "parent",
start: function (event, ui) {
// get the initial position(index) of item
var start_pos = ui.item.attr('id');
ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
},

update: function (event, ui) {
var start_pos = ui.item.attr('id');//position of dragged
// alert(start_pos);
var sortedIDs = $( "#sortable" ).sortable( "toArray" );
console.log(sortedIDs);
 // Iterate over all <li> elements
 var new_pos=((sortedIDs.indexOf(start_pos))+1);
 // alert(new_pos);

  if (start_pos < new_pos) {
   //update the items before the re-ordered item
  for(var i=new_pos; i > 0; i--){
  $(this).attr('id', (i-1));    
   }
}
 else {
  //update the items after the re-ordered item
   for(var i=new_pos+2;i <= $("#sortable li").length; i++){
    $(this).attr('id', (i-1));
      }
     }
},

    axis: 'y'
});
});
```